# Can I use the PHP operator && for 3 values like a && b && c?

Tags: php

Can I use the PHP operator && for 3 values like a && b && c?

Is this row of code correct?

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['a']) && isset($_COOKIE['b']) && isset($_COOKIE['c'])){
```

Comment: Sure, It is a logic gate. 
It is used in conditionals, there are some types, the most common are 'AND' (&&), 'OR' (||) and 'NOT'(!).

Comment: Have you tried it and see what happens?

Comment: thank you all for your answers, I'm new at this language and I made an oversight and it didn't work. Anyway, it's working now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. '&&' is the logical 'AND' operator and not the assignment '&'. For your 'IF' statement the result will be True only of all three values are True.
More info can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: thank you all for your answers, I'm new at this language and I made an oversight and it didn't work. Anyway, it's working now.